# Cleansng and replacing data with a complex hierarchy

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have data with complex hierarchy - lists, dicts, strings.
I need to find all values contains '?', remove it and all that comes after it and insert the cleaned back.
I do not understand how to do it correctly - it's kinda complicated for my current level.

I tried for strings in list:

```
    parsed["data"] = [{'dimensions':[{'name': '608907?afwafaw'}], 'metrics': [1.0, 2.0]}, {'dimensions':[{'name': '189812?awfawg'}], 'metrics': [2.0, 3.0]}]
```

I expect:

```
parsed["data"] = [{'dimensions':[{'name': '608907'}], 'metrics': [1.0, 2.0]}, {'dimensions':[{'name': '189812'}], 'metrics': [2.0, 3.0]}]
```

without any '?blablabla', just int

Comment: Are you just cleaning strings?

Comment: Try getting the position of the first '?' and then slicing the string from the start to the position found. You'll probably have to create functions to recursively iterate the different collection types and then call the string parser.

Comment: Are all your data exactly these three levels, or is there more nesting than you show in this example?

Comment: Is all the cleaning restricted to the values of `parsed["data"][ n ]["dimensions"][ m ]["name"]` (for various `n, m`), or are there other text values that may need cleaning?

Comment: @Adirio yeah, i need just integers there

Comment: @alexis it's api responce i get with parsed = req.json(). There are more data with headers etc, no need to cleance anyting alse but parsed["data"]

Comment: I'm asking about the bottom of the tree, not the top... is everything to be cleaned next to a key called "name"?

Comment: @alexis, everything till the end of list parsed["data"], nothing more

Comment: Please read my question(s) again

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution without any external dependencies, this should work for any deep objects:

```
...
parsed["data"] = [{'dimensions':[{'name': '608907?afwafaw'}], 'metrics': [1.0, 2.0]}, {'dimensions':[{'name': '189812?awfawg'}], 'metrics': [2.0, 3.0]}]

def cleanse(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in obj.keys():
            obj[key] = cleanse(obj[key])
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in range(len(obj)):
            obj[i] = cleanse(obj[i])
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.split('?')[0] # split at question mark and take only the first part, which is a number
    return obj


cleanse(parsed['data'])

print(parsed['data']) # output: [{'dimensions': [{'name': '608907'}], 'metrics': [1.0, 2.0]}, {'dimensions': [{'name': '189812'}], 'metrics': [2.0, 3.0]}]
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I had in mind when I asked him if all he needed to clean were strings. The only difference is that i was gonna clean also the dict keys, which would require an auxiliar dict.

Comment: This is by far the best answer as it doesnt require a fixed data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If all your data looks like your example, this should do it:

```
for record in parsed["data"]:
    for dim in record["dimensions"]:
        dim["name"] = dim["name"].split("?")[0]
```

It only checks "name" in "dimensions", since that's the values that need cleaning. It doesn't bother to check if the value already contains a question mark, since this will be a no-op if it does not.